# Customize edit.php Pages listing in dashboard to show only pages with a particular template applied?

Tags: page-template

The question says it all, I think.  I'd like to create a new submenu page using edit.php which will only display pages which use a certain template file (or files).

Possible?

Comment: Is the goal to have the particular posts show only specific pages on front end or back end of the site? If it's the front end, have you tried a using [Conditional Tags:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_a_Page_Template)  `<?php if ( is_page_template('single.php')) { /* Your Code Here */ }`

Comment: I'd like to show them on the backend, in the Dashboard.  Basically, I want to copy the Pages listing page but only show pages that have, say, the homepage.php template applied to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

// add submenu page
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_template_submenu');   
function add_template_submenu()
{
    add_pages_page( 'My Template', 'My Template', 'edit_pages', 'edit.php?post_type=page&template=your-template-file.php');
}

// check for the template name passed in $_GET and add it to the query
add_filter('parse_query', 'filter_pages');  
function filter_pages($query)
{
    global $typenow, $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $typenow == 'page' && $_GET['template'])
    {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = '_wp_page_template';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['template'];
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks jessica.  I answered my own question before I saw your reply but yours looks like it would work too, and is more elegant.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_action('admin_menu','add_home_page_menu');
    add_action('load-edit.php', 'filter_home_pages_mysql_action'); 

    function add_home_page_menu(){
        add_pages_page('Home Pages Menu', 'Home Pages', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=page&page_template=home_pages');
        add_pages_page('Landing Pages Menu', 'Landing Pages', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=page&page_template=landing_pages');
    }


    function filter_home_pages_mysql_action() {
        if ($_GET['post_type'] !== 'page') return;
        switch($_GET['page_template']){
            case 'home_pages':
                add_filter('posts_where', 'home_pages_where_filter') );
                add_filter('posts_join', 'join_filter') );
                break;
            case 'landing_pages':
                add_filter('posts_where', 'landing_pages_where_filter') );
                add_filter('posts_join', 'join_filter') );
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    function home_pages_where_filter($sql) {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = " AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE 'template-homepage-grid-%.php'" . $sql;
        return $sql;
    }

    function landing_pages_where_filter($sql) {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = " AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE 'template-landing.php'" . $sql;
        return $sql;
    }

    function join_filter($sql) {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = " JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id " . $sql;
        return $sql;
    }
```